# how to easily handle a datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

i made a sudoku game using windows forms, the datagrid was very easy to handle, for example

```
dataGridView1[2,3]=5;
```

now in wpf the datagrid cant be used like this and i need to find the easiest way to test and fill the grid, for example i had codes like :

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    for (k = j + 1; k < 9; k++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1[i, k].Value != null)....

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not read the content of the dataGridView. Instead I would bind a control (such as the datagridview) to a data structure that represents the values in the Sudoku.

This would allow you to simply check the data structure (even add methods, properties and events to it)

Just make a Grid (9x9 cells) and a textblock in each cell and bind the text property of each cell to an element of a two dimensional array:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Cells[0][0]}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Cells[1][0]}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Cells[2][0]}"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

And set the Grid's DataContext in code:

```
class Sudoku
{
    public int[,] Cells = new int[9,9];
    ...
}


private Sudoku _sudoku;

MainWindow_Loaded(...)
{
    _sudoku = new Sudoku();
    grid.DataContext= _sudoku;

}
```

Now you can simply set and check `_sudoku.Cells[2,3]`

Comment: thanks for the help! anw in xaml section, Binding Path=Cells[0,0] won't work. it must be Binding Path=Cells[0][0]